# python: Regex matching file extension

Tags: python, regex

hi i am trying to get the extension of the file called in a url (eg `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2 HTTP/1.1`) and get the query parameters passed to the file too.

What would be the best way to the extension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`urlparse.urlparse()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) and [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

Comment: You should probably just rsplit on `.` rather than use `os.path` in this case, as a URL and a filepath are different things. Using `os.path.splitext` would go wrong on an operating system where the file extension separator isn't `.`. Admittedly there are vanishingly few of those today.

Comment: wouldn't rsplit mathc the ver=1.3.2 path too ?

Comment: You would use it on the results of `urlparse()`.

Comment: As a rule URL path manipulations should probably be done with posixpath.