# How to safely get the file extension from a URL?

Tags: python, file

Consider the following URLs

```
http://m3u.com/tunein.m3u
http://asxsomeurl.com/listen.asx:8024
http://www.plssomeotherurl.com/station.pls?id=111
http://22.198.133.16:8024
```

Whats the proper way to determine the file extensions (.m3u/.asx/.pls)? Obviously the last one doesn't have a file extension.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that m3u/asx/pls are playlists (textfiles) for audio streams and must be parsed differently. The goal determine the extension and then send the url to the proper parsing-function. E.g.

```
url = argv[1]
ext = GetExtension(url)
if ext == "pls":
  realurl = ParsePLS(url)
elif ext == "asx":
  realurl = ParseASX(url)
(etc.)
else:
  realurl = url
Play(realurl)
```

GetExtension() should return the file extension (if any), preferrably without connecting to the URL.

Comment: You may find this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277030/ useful.

Comment: what are you expecting in the case with no extension?

Comment: What do you want to do with the file extension, and how will you handle the file not matching the file type you thought that extension should have?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The *real* proper way is to not use file extensions at all. Do a GET (or HEAD) request to the URL in question, and use the returned "Content-type" HTTP header to get the content type. File extensions are unreliable.

See [MIME types (IANA media types)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) for more information and a list of useful MIME types.

Comment: True, but what if you want a gui to pop up to save the thing? What filename do you use, and what extension do you put in your save dialog - given the URL _and_ the content-type headers?

Comment: @Spacedman: You should check if the URL path extension matches response mimetype (`mimetypes.guess_extension` might be helpful) - if not append the correct one. AFAIK that's what web browsers do.

Comment: What if "Content-type" header is missing?

Comment: Note that using mime types is also unreliable. Sometimes a web server cannot determine the mime type, and returns "application/octet-stream" by default. See: bitkeys.work/btc_balance_sorted.csv. Mime-type in this case is "text/csv" but the header shows "application/octet-stream". This is why you also need to check the file extension (or, maybe better, the file header/signature). Also mimetypes.guess_extension is useless in this scenario. More info on checking file signatures: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic and https://github.com/schlerp/pyfsig.

Answer (score 58):

Use `urlparse` to parse the path out of the URL, then `os.path.splitext` to get the extension.

```
import os
try:
    import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'http://www.plssomeotherurl.com/station.pls?id=111'
path = urlparse.urlparse(url).path
ext = os.path.splitext(path)[1]
```

Note that the extension may not be a reliable indicator of the type of the file.  The HTTP `Content-Type` header may be better.

Comment: Quick note: For Python 3 you should use urllib.parse: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html. Otherwise you will get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'` exception

Answer (score 48):

This is easiest with `requests` and `mimetypes`:

```
import requests
import mimetypes

response = requests.get(url)
content_type = response.headers['content-type']
extension = mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type)
```

The extension includes a dot prefix. For example, `extension` is `'.png'` for content type `'image/png'`.

Comment: BTW this assumes you want to retrieve the contents of the URL.

Comment: mimetypes's `guess_extension` function does have it's quirks though. Hand `request` a url for a file with the '.jpg' extension and it identifies it as MIME type 'image/jpeg'. Hand that over to `mimetypes` and ask it for a reasonable extension and it spits out '.jpe'. Not wrong, just... not helpful.

Comment: @brokkr yeah .jpe is valid, but that sounds like a bug to me, like `guess_extension` isn't pulling the most likely/popular from a list of valid extensions.

Comment: Whether bug or WAI it simple seems to pick the first in a list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396288/68595

Comment: response = response.head(url) is more efficient for this task

Comment: @acarayol if you're not interested in the resource itself, then yes you are correct.

Answer (score 6):

File extensions are basically meaningless in URLs. For example, if you go to http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/source/browse/branches/release-2009Q1-maint/Lib/psyco/support.py?r=292 do you want the extension to be ".py" despite the fact that the page is HTML, not Python?

Use the Content-Type header to determine the "type" of a URL.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ python3
Python 3.1.2 (release31-maint, Sep 17 2010, 20:27:33) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from os.path import splitext
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse 
>>> 
>>> urls = [
...     'http://m3u.com/tunein.m3u',
...     'http://asxsomeurl.com/listen.asx:8024',
...     'http://www.plssomeotherurl.com/station.pls?id=111',
...     'http://22.198.133.16:8024',
... ]
>>> 
>>> for url in urls:
...     path = urlparse(url).path
...     ext = splitext(path)[1]
...     print(ext)
... 
.m3u
.asx:8024
.pls

>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the content-type you can write a function one like I have written using urllib2.
If you need to utilize page content anyway it is likely that you will use urllib2 so no need to import os.

```
import urllib2

def getContentType(pageUrl):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(pageUrl)
    pageHeaders = page.headers
    contentType = pageHeaders.getheader('content-type')
    return contentType
```

Answer (score 1):

Use urlparse, that'll get most of the above sorted:

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

then split the "path" up. You might be able to split the path up using os.path.split, but your example 2 with the :8024 on the end needs manual handling. Are your file extensions always three letters? Or always letters and numbers? Use a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach that takes nothing else into account except for the actual file extension from a url:

```
def fileExt( url ):
    # compile regular expressions
    reQuery = re.compile( r'\?.*$', re.IGNORECASE )
    rePort = re.compile( r':[0-9]+', re.IGNORECASE )
    reExt = re.compile( r'(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$)', re.IGNORECASE )

    # remove query string
    url = reQuery.sub( "", url )

    # remove port
    url = rePort.sub( "", url )

    # extract extension
    matches = reExt.search( url )
    if None != matches:
        return matches.group( 1 )
    return None
```

*edit: added handling of explicit ports from :1234*

Answer (score 0):

you can try the [rfc6266](https://github.com/g2p/rfc6266) module like：

```
import requests
import rfc6266

req = requests.head(downloadLink)
headersContent = req.headers['Content-Disposition']
rfcFilename = rfc6266.parse_headers(headersContent, relaxed=True).filename_unsafe
filename = requests.utils.unquote(rfcFilename)
```

Comment: For safe names, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names/68807910#68807910

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old topic, but this oneliner is what did:

```
file_ext = "."+ url.split("/")[-1:][0].split(".")[-1:][0]
```

Assumption is that there is a file extension.

Comment: It would work to just take this last split:
`file_ext = "." + url.split(".")[-1]`