# Why the various JPEG Extensions?

Tags: python, mime-types, image, jpeg

While working on a downloader, I've encountered the following with Python's `mimetypes.guess_extension` function:

```
In [2]: mimetypes.guess_extension('image/jpeg', strict=False)
Out[2]: '.jpe'
```

I knew that *jpeg* and *jpg* are valid JPEG extensions, but I didn't know about *jpe*. So looking at the wikipedia site did reveal the following:

> The most common filename extensions for files employing JPEG compression are .jpg and .jpeg, though .jpe, .jfif and .jif are also used

Even more extensions I didn't know of.

So the main question: Why does JPEG have so many (valid) extensions associated with it?

On a related note I'd like to know why Python does return 'jpe' and not 'jpg' or 'jpeg' since I see these used the most.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears `mimetypes.guess_extension` returns the first of all possible extensions:

```
def guess_extension(self, type, strict=True):
    # ...
    extensions = self.guess_all_extensions(type, strict)
    if not extensions:
        return None
    return extensions[0]
```

So you'll get whichever is first in the list returned by `mimetypes.guess_all_extensions`, which turns out to be:

```
>>> mimetypes.guess_all_extensions('image/jpeg', strict=False)
['.jpe', '.jpg', '.jpeg']
```

My guess as to why `.jpe` is also valid:

In DOS and early Windows versions filenames could only have 8 characters and 3 characters for the extension (see the article [8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) on Wikipedia for more info). It could be that they abbreviated JPEG to .JPE or .jpe - which is why we now have .jpe, .jpeg and .jpg.

It's indeed true that .jpeg and .jpg are more common.

Answer (score 2):

In a strict sense jpeg is an image compression algorithm, not a file format.

JFIF (JPEG File Interchange Format) is the usual file format that uses jpeg compression.
EXIF (Exchangeable image file format) is another format using jpeg, used in digital camera. 
Most people tend to think those format are the same, but that's not the case.

TIFF can also be jpeg encoded.

Comment: While the information is true, it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Please... It asks why several extensions are used, including ".jfif", so I explain jfif and what it means compared to jpeg.

Comment: The 8.3 dos limitation may explain ".jpe" but that's only a part of the question.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is partially relevant, but there is some irrelevant information squashed in (EXIF is not really relevant here) and the connection to the concrete Python problem is missing. Maybe I'm overreacting, but then again: it's just a downvote ;-)

Comment: That's just the "main question" according to original question. I think I need to use exit and tiff example to explain jfif is not the only jpeg encoded file format. It just a downvote, but on a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Makes my head clearer about mime-type -> extension relations! However it was not _exactly_ the answer I was looking for. But thanks :)