# Regular expression for matching something up till a point

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to match some sub strings in an url.

Eg url's :-

```
www.google.com/images

www.google.com/images.pdf
```

Currently I have the `re = r"([^.]*$)"`

This works for case 1 as intended but fails for 2.

`www.google.com/images.pdf` matches `.pdf` -> Working as intended

`www.google.com/images` matches `.com/images`  -> Failing

I want the re to not match when it cannot find a `.` and finds the first `/` from the end.

Please don't suggest doing this with `.endswith`. I don't have the list of all possible extensions that I need to match.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want but how about `r"(\.[^./]*$)"`? [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/Fs6QYh/1)

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's exactly what I want !! Can you please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct. And if possible a small write on what's happening ? Thanks a ton !

Comment: @anubhava It doesn't sadly. It matches /images.pdf instead of just .pdf.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but it seems you want to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776924/how-to-safely-get-the-file-extension-from-a-url If you just look at strings of URLs then never mind

Comment: @DerMolly Interesting find. I should've found that. That might be something I can use. But for now Michael's answer works for me. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use expression `r"(\.[^./]*$)"`

It's best to look at it from end to beginning:

From end of line take as much text characters as possible which are neither a `/` (so the whole match belongs to last path element) nor a `.` so not more than the possible suffix is eaten. Finally (at the beginning) there must be a `.` in the match so the whole match is the suffix of the last path element (usually a file) if present.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/[^\.]*(\..*)$
```

From left to right, this says: look for a forward slash, followed by any string of characters excluding a period ("`[^\.]`") any number of times ("`*`"), then look for the string starting with a period ("`\.`") followed by any remaining characters.  But do all of this from the end ("`$`"). I've noticed "`[^.]`" seems to work in place of "`[^\.]`" too, so maybe my "`\.`" is redundant here.