# Python: Can't create a binary file with a "with open(xxxxx)" line, using an os.path generated path (single backslash passed as double?)

Tags: python, binaryfiles, file-writing

I'm trying to download a video from vimeo (with this code https://github.com/moettle/hidden-vimeo-downloader, with some modified info for the request session info), and in the part of writing the file, I get an [Errno 22] message, as if the `with open(PATH, "wb")` read the backslashes as double backslashes

i.e: if PATH is something like "folder\filename.txt", the terminal's output shows
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'folder\filename.txt'

This is my code:

```
    r = requests.get(current_segement_url)
    v_seg_file = os.path.join(out_video ,"video-" + segment_base_name + str(i) + segment_base_ext)

# Just to print out the actual variable's content
    print(v_seg_file)

    with open(v_seg_file, "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

(i've separated the path to `v_seg_file` to see if the .encode() method or playing with replacements or raw strings could work, but it doesn't.)

The current output is:

> ```
> segments_video_8cf150a5-2ce1-4adc-bb37-111111111111\video-segment-0.m4s?r=11111111dHJhbDE%3D
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\XXXXX\.......\hidden-vimeo-downloader\vimeo-downloader.py", line 78, in <module>
> with open(v_seg_file, "wb") as f:
>          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'segments_video_8cf150a5-2ce1-4adc-bb37-111111111111\\video-segment-0.m4s?r=11111111dHJhbDE%3D'
> ```
>
> (the actual file path was modified here, but it's generated automatically by the code)

The question is: Why can't I create the file?
Some lines above, the directory is created if it doesn't exist.
I also tried writing in "wb", "wb+", "w+b" without success

I think the problem is that `with open(` here somehow transforms a single backslash into two?
I mean, the printed output of `v_seg_file` is OK, which has been created with `os.path.join` (that should be OK)

I also tried another script to test this writing statements just as a double check, and it works fine for non-binary writing.

```
import os

out_video = "folder"
segment_base_name = "xxx"
segment_base_ext = "yyy"
i = 0

v_seg_file = os.path.join(out_video ,"video-" + segment_base_name + str(i) + segment_base_ext)

print(v_seg_file)

if not os.path.exists(out_video):
    os.makedirs(out_video)
    print("Directory created successfully!")
else:
    print("Directory already exists!")

with open(v_seg_file, "w") as f:
    f.write("file written")
```

(result: the file `folder\video-xxx0yyy` was created without issues, and consists of only one line of text "file written")

Could this be a platform issue with the BINARY writing? I'm running this code locally in a Windows machine, but yesterday i run it in Github codespaces (with another video URL) and worked fine.

Comment: `video-segment-0.m4s?r=11111111dHJhbDE%3D` is not a valid filename, you can't have question marks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to safely get the file extension from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776924/how-to-safely-get-the-file-extension-from-a-url)

Comment: but when I run this code in github codespaces, the file with a "?" in the filename was effectively created. I'll check this as soon as I can (wasn't aware that this could be the conflict) and get back to see if this was the problem. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: There's a chance codespaces is not running Windows, which is consistent with your statement that the file was created.  Have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/6340496), regarding forbidden filename characters.  Likely, you'll need to clean the filename before attempting to create the file on Win.

Comment: Yes, sir! (or ma'am) This was the problem indeed. That question mark in the middle was throwing the error. Thanks to all who helped here! @s3dev how can I mark your help as an answer to the problem? (I'm new to asking and answering here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are, codespaces is running Linux, hence why the file creation worked there. Windows and *nix have different rules regarding what characters are allowed in a filename.

Please refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/6340496) for more specifics.

As you’re on Windows, there are many disallowed characters, *specifically for your case, a question mark*. The file being binary vs plaintext, has no bearing here.

#### The fix:

You’ll need to clean the filename before attempting to create the file on Win.

Tip:
The Python [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method is very useful for making multiple replacements in a string.

Comment: Thanks, in this particular case, just keeping the ".m4s" extension was enough. I stripped off the last part of the string including the question mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your path uses either raw strings (`rpath`) or replaces backslashes with forward slashes (`folder/filename.txt`). In python, backslashes are escape characters, often leading to issues like yours when used in file paths. Also, check your path and filename for any unsupported characters, as they can trigger an `Errno 22`. If modifying the path doesn't help, manually print and verify the path for accuracy or potential hidden characters.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the question mark in the filename. The slashes were ok

Answer (score -1):

Use Raw string.
example:

```
file path = r".\your-path"
```

Put 'r' in front of your directory.

Comment: While this *will* read the backslash as a character rather than an escape; it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: Right. This MAY work for a specific string, but I have a variable as a PATH. I tried different versions of rf'PATH_VAR', but doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

If your path is folder\filename.txt then you'll need either r"folder\filename.txt" or "folder\\filename.txt". This is because \f is interpreted as formfeed (0x0C). Furthermore, the directory "folder" will have to exist in your current working directory **and** you'll need permission to write in that directory

Comment: in fact, this folder\filename.txt is the code that actually works. The problem is when I try to write a binary file

Comment: @CtrlZ: I downvoted your answer, because it isn't the correct solution for the error message in the question.

Comment: @Anonymous My answer is based on " if PATH is something like "folder\filename.txt", the terminal's output shows OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'folder\filename.txt'" from the OP. But well done for downvoting nonetheless

Comment: Best to base one's answers on what the error message says, not on someone's interpretation of what the error message says.

Comment: @Anonymous Thank you for your advice. I'll bear it in mind